# Fetch posts list from fist CPT taxonomy term and list under 2. CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, get-posts

I have two custom post types registered.

1. Custom Post Type: PUBLIKATIONEN with the two custom taxonomies LISTEN and AUTOREN
2. Custom Post Type: AUTOREN

Both have archives.

With: `<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'writers' ); ?>` I can list all posts of the Custom Post Type AUTOREN (= writer's profiles) on a PUBLIKATIONEN post. But what I want to do is to list only the posts of the writers who have contributed to a certain publication.

Basically it's like this

1. Custom Post Type:

   - PUBLIKATIONEN = Custom Post Type
   - AUTOREN = Taxonomy
   - Name = Term
2. Custom Post Type:

   - AUTOREN = Custom Post Type
   - Name = Terms (no Taxonomy)

So I need to fetch the terms of the PUBLIKATIONEN post and list them as post under AUTOREN Custom Post Type using a specific template (single-autoren.php).

This is what I have come up with so far, but really no idea how to set this up properly:

```
//Get Autoren Posts
function get_post_type_archive_link_custom( $myquery ) {

    $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'post_type' => 'publikationen', 
            'taxonomy' => 'autoren',
            'terms' => array('autoren'),
            'field' => 'slug',
        ),
        array(
            'post_type' => 'autoren',   
            'terms' => array('autoren'),
            'field' => 'slug',
        ),
    );

    query_posts($myquery);

    wp_reset_query();
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_post_type_archive_link_custom' );
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have a custom post type and a custom taxonomy of writer?

Comment: Because the custom post type WRITERS is for posts (writer's profiles) and the custom taxonomy assigned to CPT PUBLICATIONS is for selecting which writers have contributed to a certain publication. Basically the whole CPT thing is to make it easy for the customer to enter data, but if I had known that CPT's is not just another version of categories and tags I would've gone down the category & tags road.

Comment: I think that Post 2 Post would be a better solution for you. Removes the proxy Writers taxonomy. This plugin is written by some big names in WP, so it's a trusted tool for sure. https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/